# Creación de una matriz con bucle for en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, matriz

Recién estoy empezando a aprender Python y el ejercicio de creación con un bucle for de la matriz  cuya imagen está más abajo me está costando. Gracias desde ya por la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por el comentario. Abajo está el código que pude hacer para crear la matriz "contraria" a la pedida pero no estoy encontrando la forma de modificarlo para crear la matriz objetivo

```
k = 0
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        k += 1
        print(k, end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: Hola Marcelo, te recomiendo visitar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Debes agregar el código en el que estés trabajando y/o la investigación que has llevado a cabo hasta el momento, ademas de preguntar por un error o problema concreto.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la pronta respuesta. Abajo está el código que pude hacer para crear la matriz "contraria" a la pedida pero no estoy encontrando la forma de modificarlo para crear la matriz objetivo

```
k = 0
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        k += 1
        print(k, end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: Esta es la sección de respuestas. Si deseas añadir información a tu respuesta debes de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/605807/edit) tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La forma "*básica*" de abordar el problema es creando una matriz (lista) justo con el código que tienes. O sea, en vez de imprimir, vas asignando los valores a la lista. Luego la lista resultante se recorre otra vez de forma invertida para imprimir las filas como si fueran columnas:

```python
num_rows = 6
num_cols = 6

matrix = []
k = 0
for i in range(num_rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for _ in range(num_cols):
        k += 1
        matrix[i].append(k)

for i in range(num_cols):
    for j in range(num_rows):
        print(matrix[j][i], end=" ")
    print()
```

---

Otra forma es calculando los valores de cada columna directamente. Guiándome de tu ejemplo, se imprimen los valores sin crear la matriz.

```python
num_rows = 6
num_cols = 6

for i in range(num_rows):
    k = i+1
    for _ in range(num_cols):
        print(k, end = " ")
        k += num_rows
    print()
```

En ambos casos puedes variar `num_rows` o `num_cols` como quieras.